# how to convert json data into a list of values (for linechart)

Tags: javascript, json

i have json data in following format.

```
{
    "2" : {
        "question" : "How did you like our Food?",
        "avg_rating" : {
            "2016-05-23" : 3.7142857142857,
            "2016-05-25" : 4.5
        }
    },
    "3" : {
        "question" : "How did you like our drinks?",
        "avg_rating" : {
            "2016-05-23" : 3.4285714285714,
            "2016-05-25" : 4
        }
    }
}
```

i want it to be formatted in following format where above data should be inside data variable of plot object.

```
var plot = [{
                label: "",
                data: [
                   [2016-05-23, 3.7142857142857],[2016-05-25, 4.5]
],
                points: {fillColor: '#006699'}
            },{
                label: "",
                data: [
                    [2016-05-23, 3.4285714285714],[2016-05-25, 4]
],
                points: {fillColor: '#009933'}
            }];
```

i am not good in english so i may not have been able to explain this problem properly. please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: Where does `fillColor` come from? Is `label` empty each time?

Comment: fillcolor are static data and label will always be empty.

Comment: But have you tried anything? Any attempt to show? (Sorry I'm at work right now, it's very hard to reply much more often.)